# Administrative privileges

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

In a thread here I found a way to check whether a user has administrative privileges. However, when I try to use boolean logic on this it fails to work.

```
$user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)  

if($user = $false){cls;Write-warning "Starting and stopping services can only be done with administrative privileges.`nPlease restart this script from an elevated prompt!";Read-host;exit
}
```

The problem is, whilst running the script from my computer without initiating Powershell with Administrative rights the text "False" comes up. However, the if statement does not kick in. Am I defining it wrong?

EDIT: When I use `$true` instead of `$false` the if statement kicks in both when I do and don't run the script from an elevated prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your condition `$user = $false`:

1. It's not a condition in the first place. `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator. You need `-eq` to check for equality.
2. `$user` is not a boolean value. What you actually want to check here is the return value of the `IsInRole()` method. However, you never assign it to a variable, so you can't use it elsewhere in your code.

Change your code to this:

```
$user    = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$isAdmin = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)

if (-not $isAdmin) {
  cls
  Write-warning "Starting and stopping services can ..."
  Read-host
  exit
}
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I actually had the -eq in my original script. God knows why I wrote '=' here. I wonder however; where does the new object go when I don't assign it to a variable? Null?

Comment: It will linger in memory until the garbage collector disposes of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems curious to me..  Can't you just update the following to be do the same checking:

```
if !($isAdmin) {
  cls
  Write-warning "Starting and stopping services can ..."
  Read-host
  exit
}
```

Comment: That would raise an error. `!` and `-not` have the same meaning (negate the next condition), but they **must** be inside the parentheses.