# PowerShell command to check whether an application is running with elevated privileges

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I require a PowerShell command or script which will check whether my console application is running as administrator or not. If it is not running as administrator, I will stop it and run again using the script.

If PowerShell command is not available, is there any other way to check this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if logged on user is an administrator when non-elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129787/check-if-logged-on-user-is-an-administrator-when-non-elevated)

Comment: See also [Running a command as Administrator using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57035712/1701026)

Comment: Not exactly. I will be running the script as admin only. So no need to check log on user. I just wanted to check about application, whether running as elevated or not

Comment: Is https://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/powershell-test-isadmin/ useful?

Comment: @jeff Zeitlin I want to check for particular application.

Comment: Checking whether or not a process is running elevated is not the same as checking whether or not an user is a member of Administrators role. These two are quite different operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my [`Test-ProcessElevated` cmdlet](https://gist.github.com/0xfeeddeadbeef/ce341bbca071099fd6952abab896aaac) (It is too long, I've posted to GitHub gist).

For example:

```
# from pipeline:
Get-Process notepad | Test-ProcessElevated

# from parameter:
Test-ProcessElevated $(Get-Process notepad)

# it returns boolean
if (ps notepad | Test-ProcessElevated)
{
    Write-Host 'notepad is running elevated.'
}

# dwm.exe is running in a different session:
ps dwm | Test-ProcessElevated
```

I've tested it in both Windows PowerShell 5 and PowerShell 7.

Comment: Hey, it is working and giving expected results. Thank you 

Comment: I'm getting one exception. Can you please help me out here...                                               
                                                                       Exception calling "IsProcessElevated" with "1" argument (s): "OperProcessToken failed"

At line:161 char:16

return [SecurityUtils.Win32]::IsProcessElevated($Process)

: NotSpecified: (:) , MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId: Win32Exception

+ Category Info

notepad is not running elevated.

Comment: I just noticed that, when my application is running as elevated it is throwing this exception. And in if condition it is still giving process is not running as elevated.

Comment: Turns out opening a process that is running in a different session is not a simple task , even if you are an Administrator. Additional privileges are required. I'll look into this.

Comment: @ShivaniG I've solved the problem. See the updated script: https://gist.github.com/0xfeeddeadbeef/ce341bbca071099fd6952abab896aaac

Comment: Here's what needed to be changed:  https://gist.github.com/0xfeeddeadbeef/ce341bbca071099fd6952abab896aaac/revisions